# how to get geo boundaries of country in python

Tags: python, geospatial

I am using faker lib to generate lat,lng randomly within a specific country . But, the generated lat, lng are getting generated in same location. I want to generate some data which is spread across the country. I am trying to add miles but the lat lng sometime goes out of the geo boundaries. What is the best way to get the geo boundaries so that I can check if lat,lng belong to the country.

The referred question [Generating Random Cordinates for Specific Country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503920/generating-random-cordinates-for-specific-country)  doesn't answer my need as it is generating lat,lng nearby not uniform spread of the data point.

Other way - How To generate or get the geo boundaries of the country.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating Random Cordinates for Specific Country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503920/generating-random-cordinates-for-specific-country)

Comment: It gives lat,lng in nearby vicinity not spread across the country.

Comment: check out the library shapely. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73230

Comment: https://github.com/datasets/geo-countries/blob/master/data/countries.geojson